# Seleccionar al siguiente elemento similar usando js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, nodos

Tengo una tabla con una fila algo asi...

```js
let id = document.getElementById('myID');
let cod = id.parentNode.nextSibling;
console.log(cod);
```

```html
<tr> 
  <td>
     <span id="myID">1</span>
  </td>
  <td>34132</td>
  <td>Juan</td>
  <td>Reyes</td>
 </tr>
```

Lo que intento es obtener el codigo, osea el segundo **td** pero el **nextSibling** me extrae el primer nodo inmediato, osea el salto de linea. No quiero tener que poner otro **NextSibling**, si bien de esa forma resolveria el problema, si alguien en alguno momento borra ese espacio o aumenta otro salto entre medio dejaria de funcionar y seria muy complicado darle seguimiento.

Lo que quiero basicamente es lo mismo que hace la funcion NEXT() de JQUERY pero sin JQUERY solo con JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo situándote en su ancestro **tr** primero mediante `closest()`, y luego, sabiendo la columna, y mediante `querySelectorAll()`, te situas en la columna mediante su índice, en este caso sería el **1**, de este modo:

```js
let id = document.getElementById('myID');
let cod = id.closest("tr").querySelectorAll("td")[1];
console.log(cod.textContent)
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span id="myID">1</span>
    </td>
    <td>34132</td>
    <td>Juan</td>
    <td>Reyes</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, si me sirvió tu respuesta.